# Concatenating a char into a string

Tags: c, string, loops, char, concatenation

I am trying to read a string from the console. But I want to read it char by char. And I'm having trouble with concatenating the char into the string AND with breaking the loop.
Here is the code:

```
char* createString(){
    char c;
    char *string;
    int x=0;

    string = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    do{
        c = getche();
        if(c != '\n'){
            x++;
            realloc(string, sizeof(char)*x);
            strcat(string, &c);
        };
    }while(c != '\n');
    return string;
};
```

When I run this code, each concatenation adds 3 chars, instead of just 1. It's like is accessing non-allocated memory... (For example, if I press `a`, the final string is `a%T`. Then, if I press another key, `s` for example, string becomes `a%Ts%T`)

And when I press `Enter`, it goes into the if and doesn't get out of the loop.

I have no clue of why and what is going on...

---

### EDIT

---

Based on other tries and responses until now, I changed my code and now it's like this:

```
char* digitarString(){
    char c[2];
    char *string;

    string = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    do{
        c[0] = getche();
        c[1] = '\0';
        if(c[0] != '\n'){
            strcat(string, c);
        };
    }while(c[0] != '\n');
    return string;
};
```

BUT, there are still two issues...

- The code works, but I think that it's writing in non-allocated memory.
- When I press `Enter` it still doesn't work. It keep entering the loop and if.

Forget about the `Enter`... I changed it...

```
c[0] = getche();
```

to

```
scanf("%c", &c[0]);
```

and worked awesomely well.

Comment: `strcat` expects pointers to 0-terminated arrays of `char`s. You don't pass that.

Comment: That updated code is wrong I'm afraid.  `strcat` doesn't allocate memory for you so you're writing an unbounded amount of data to a 1-byte array.  I guess this is working for you by chance, probably because your program doesn't allocate any further memory and doesn't free `string` so you never notice the memory corruption.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid of that too. Actually, I think that it's really happening... Do you know any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok here is the solution

```
 strcat(string, &c);
```

change this to

```
strncat(string, &c,1);
```

**now the answer to the question why ?**

well first of call the below statement

```
c = getche();
```

will scan a value for us and will place in variable called c

now lets consider the variable is placed in an arbitrary memory location x

```
    c
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|     a     |            |            |           |            |            |
+---------- +----------  +----------  +---------- +--------- - +---------- +  
  x = &c       x+1             x+2            ......
```

now to the next important statement

```
strcat(string, &c);
```

the second argument above is supposed to be a string means a NULL termination at the end but we can not guarantee that x+1 location is NULL and if x+1 is not NULL then the string will be more than a single character long and it will end up appending all those characters to your original string hence garbage.

I hope it's clear now...

P.S -  if you have access to gdb you can check practically..

Comment: Thanks, man! This helped me a lot to understand how a lot of string functions works!

Answer (score 0):

1) you should initialize

```
int x=1;
```

2) you should update this line:

```
realloc(string, sizeof(char)*x);
```

to

```
string = realloc(string, sizeof(char)*x);
```

3) Yoou do not need for strcat to concatenate. So instead of using

```
strcat(string, &c);
```

use the following lines

```
string[x-2] = c;
string[x-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char* createString(void){
    int c;
    char *string=NULL;
    int x=0;

    while(1){
        c = getche();
        string = realloc(string, sizeof(char)*(x+1));
        if('\n' != c)//input <ctrl+j> or use getchar()
            string[x++] = (char)c;
        else {
            string[x] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```